# Unit test cases in Spring boot. Service methods or Http Urls

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I am doing a web project rest api  in Spring boot and need to write unit test cases. I am confused about to write test cases for http urls using http client, or test cases for @service methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually unit tests cover public methods from @Service annotated class (and other components).

Testing with HTTP client is more like writing integration tests, which cover connection between different systems - just like in the case of HTTP API, that is called either by your different service or by other component independent from your system.

PS: Welcome on StackOverflow, I hope that you will find your answers. :)

Comment: Thanks for helpful clarification 